# Playing flv video in flash exe air application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flex3

I have embedded flv video into HTML file and when i run that in browser it plays properly.
I have created a exe file using air application, through which i want to run that flv video and display some images where images and flv are in same folder. I have given path of flv and images in a xml file. But when i run that via exe all the images get displayed, but fvl is not playing. Can anybody tel the reason? how to solve this problem?

Comment: maybe you could share some code otherwise it will be hard to help you

Comment: are loafing them as relative or absolute path ? where are the files stored (app folder ) ?

Comment: Thanks  Adrian Pirvulescu.  
 In root there is exe file and asset folder. flv path as below.
asset->cool->module->video.flv   
xml path asset->cool->shared->file.xml
html path->asset->view.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in air, look at this thread:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3718996

You need the absolute path to the file

```
var File = window.runtime.flash.filesystem.File;
flashVars.setAttribute("value","vid=" + new File(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("anFlv.flv").nativePath).url);
```